# Macro for grouping rows

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that groups blank cells together in and ignores cells with value in it and I cannot figure out how to change it so it's grouping with specific values (150, 155, 130, 115 and 110 to be exact).

My question is how can i change the code so that instead of grouping blank cells it groups cells with values in them.

So i want this

[image]

Look like this

[image]

To clarify what macro does:

It goes through every cell and it checks for value. If it has value then it skips to next cell. If cell has no value it checks next cell and if same happens then it groups those cells together.

Code:

```
Public Sub GroupCells() 
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstBlankRow As Integer, lastBlankRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim neighborColumnValue As String

    Rows("1:2000").RowHeight = 15
    Columns("A:N").ColumnWidth = 13

    'select range based on given named range
    Set myRange = Range("A7:A2000")
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    firstBlankRow = 0
    lastBlankRow = 0
    'for every row in the range
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value

        If (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
            If firstBlankRow = 0 Then
                firstBlankRow = currentRow
            End If
        ElseIf Not (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
            If firstBlankRow = 0 Then
                firstBlankRow = currentRow
            ElseIf firstBlankRow <> 0 Then
                lastBlankRow = currentRow - 1
            End If
        End If


        If firstBlankRow <> 0 And lastBlankRow <> 0 Then
            Range(Cells(firstBlankRow, myRange.Column), Cells(lastBlankRow, myRange.Column)).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Group
            firstBlankRow = 0
            lastBlankRow = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: The order of cells would play an important role. Can you sort or the code should work with whatever order it is?

Comment: will there be any blank cell among your cells? if not, it is easier

Comment: @Ibo sorry for late response, there are no blanks what so ever and the order is as shown on image. 2444 works as some kind of breaker for grouping. 150, 155, 130, 115 and 110 should be grouped together and does not matter how many of them are in a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You can modify it to fit it with more detailed conditions etc:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
    Dim bBreak As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    'I assume the values are in column A
    With WS
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Define a dictionary to store values that should be grouped
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    dict.Add 150, ""
    dict.Add 155, ""
    dict.Add 130, ""
    dict.Add 115, ""
    dict.Add 110, ""

    'Loop through the values in Column A and group them
    For i = 1 To lRow
        Set cell = WS.Cells(i, 1)
        If dict.exists(cell.Value) Then 'cell value is among values store in the dict, so it should be grouped
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell 'first cell with a value to be grouped
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        Else 'cell is a breaker value
            If rng Is Nothing Then 'there is nothing to be grouped, continue
                'do nothing
            Else 'this is the last cell of a range that should be grouped
                rng.Rows.Group 'group only rows
                Set rng = Nothing 'reset the range
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'If the last cell is not a breaker, the last cells will not be grouped
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Rows.Group 'group only rows
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak anything outside of the values stored in the dictionary will act as a breaker, blank cells included.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak please don't forget to choose the answer as the right answer to your question and upvote it since I spend quite a time to write the code for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: For some reason when i run it it does nothing.

Comment: @ArturAlbertHamelak I am sure it is working because I tested it myself. You are doing something that does not work. Do you have the numbers in column A?

Comment: It seems that numbers a formatted as text. Is it possible to change something in macro to modify value instead of numbers?

Comment: Figured it out. Converted text to number with

    `Range("A:A2000").Select
    Sheets(1).Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With`

Comment: or you can do this: `If dict.exists(cint(cell.Value))` instead of `If dict.exists(cell.Value)`

Comment: if you are getting at the line that I suggested, that means there are some values in column A that are not convertible to integers. It is hard without seeing the data you have on the sheet. Also, you can change the format of the cells manually on the sheet before running the code. I guess you paste some numbers there  and  they should be converted to numbers before you run the code. You can convert the format as you did, but a bit more professionally like `WS.Columns("A").NumberFormat="0"`